# How to get all instances of a class

Tags: python, set, instance

I am learning Python as a beginner and I'd like to create a class `Person`. In the constructor I would want to put every instance I create into a set called 'instances'. Then I'd like the instances() method to return all the instances. How can I do this?

```
class Person:

    # Type annotations
    __first_name: str
    __last_name: str
    instances: set

    # Initializing variables
    no_of_persons = 0
    instances = set()

    def __init__(self, firstname="unknown", lastname="unknown"):
        self.__first_name = firstname
        self.__last_name = lastname
        Person.no_of_persons += 1
        Person.instances.add() ## Here I have problems

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self.__first_name

    @first_name.setter
    def first_name(self, firstname):
        self.__first_name = firstname

    @property
    def last_name(self, ):
        return self.__last_name 

    @last_name.setter
    def last_name(self, lastname):
        self.__last_name = lastname

    def getFullName(self):
        """ Returns a tuple of the firstname and the lastname """
        return (self.__first_name, self.__last_name)

    def summary(self):
        """ Returns a dictionary of all instance variables """
        return {'first_name': self.__first_name,
                'last_name': self.__last_name}
    @staticmethod
    def number_of_persons():
        return Person.no_of_persons

    @staticmethod
    def instances():
        return Person.instances

p1 = Person()
Person.number_of_persons()
Person.instances()
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `type(<instance>).__subclasses__()`? Or just `<class>.__subclasses__()` if you are referencing it directly?

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation; as it is, it's not valid syntax right now.

Comment: Having the class track this is usually a mistake; it's almost always better to track objects within the context of explicit containers instead of having the class keep a list of all its instances.

Comment: I put a +1 for the question, but please consider changing the code. It is overly complicated. Simply erase everything that is not necessary please. Good luck for your futur questions !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `self` to the set.

```
Person.instances.add(self)
```

or more idiomatically

```
self.__class__.instances.add(self)
```

Also, you need to use a different name for the method that gets the instances; and it should be a classmethod, not a staticmethod.

```
@classmethod
def get_instances(cls):
    return cls.instances
```

Although really you don't need a method here at all, as you can access `Person.instances` (the attribute) directly.

Comment: Note: Since `instances` isn't assigned to, you don't need `self.__class__.instances.add(self)`; `self.instances.add(self)` will look up `instances` on the class as long as the instance doesn't shadow it with an instance-level `instances`.

Comment: Since we are only adding to `self.instances`, this code has no thread safety issues, is that correct?