# Getting list of all instances of given class

Tags: python, class, oop

Is it possible in python to get a list of all instances of given class (just like it's done by .get_lines() method in the code below) and by reffering to specific elements of that list (like it's done in twelfth line of below code by reffering to element with index 0 from the list called "lines") is it possible to modify these element? Considering that every element of that list will be an instance of some class is it possible to - for example - change value of one of the instance unique variables or create new one and give it some value? For sake of clarity I'll add that I don't mean classes from framework's or libraries like matplotlib but classes that are written by me - from scratch. I'm attaching figures that were generated by below code as a proof that it works fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line_1 = ax.axvline(8) # create vertical line at x = 8
line_2 = ax.axvline(18) # create vertical line at x = 18

plt.title('Before changing line_1\'s position')
plt.pause(1) # display figure with lines
plt.savefig('plot1.png')

lines = ax.get_lines() # get list of all instances of matplotlib's line class connceted to ax object and save it in "lines" variable
lines[0].set_xdata(12) # change line_1's position from originally set x = 8 to x = 12
plt.title('After changing line_1\'s position')
plt.pause(1) # display figure with lines after changing line_1's position
plt.savefig('plot2.png')
```

[image: Before changing line_1's position]
[image: After changing line_1's position]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all instances of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000173/how-to-get-all-instances-of-a-class)

Comment: It does. Thank you <3